# Can OptaPlanner be modified to support 2d Bin Packing

Tags: optaplanner

I am looking for a algorithm that will place different size rectangle given their Height and width in inches on a Fixed size rectangle which is defines by Height and Width. 
I saw bin packing in a description of OptaPlanner but I am not sure this is what I am looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Users have done it before IIRC, but it's still painful to do 2D **surface** bin packing (or 3D *volume* bin packing for that matter).

In academic papers, there's a technique that works well for such cases: put the items in an ordered queue and then assign them into the container(s) with a Construction Heuristic (usually First Fit Decreasing). Then use metaheuristics (usually Tabu Search or Late Acceptance) to optimize the order of that queue, while running the CH to evaluate every new ordering. This feature, lets call it "MH on CH-using score calculation", isn't implemented in OptaPlanner out of the box yet. I am planning to add it in 6.3 or later, with a surface or volume bin packing example.

For inspiration, you might (or might not) want to look at [my Packing Santa's Sleigh experiment](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/packing-santas-sleigh) (warning: here be dragons), which implements a variant on 3D volume bin packing defined by a Kaggle competition. It yields feasible solutions, but was never finished.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I certainly do not need 3D packing since all the rectangles are flat. I was just looking for a way to put 2D rectangles into a bigger rectangle